# Removing strings from lists and removing numbers from lists

Tags: scheme

```
(define p1 '(4 "the" "dog" "chewed" "the" "rug"))

(define p2 '(79 "on" "the" "rug" "slept" "the" "dog"))

(define p3 '(32 "the" "rug" "rats" "slept" "on"))

(define p4 '(42 "the" "meaning" "of" "life"))
```

Given lists p1-p4 I want to write a function called get-page-number that would pull out the number from the list. Example:

`(get-page-number p2)` would return 79

Then I need to write a function called get-words that would get rid of the number and return the strings. Example:

`(get-words p1)` would return "the" "dog" "chewed" "the" "rug"

Comment: Is the number always the first element of the list or do you need to search for a number amongst the elements?

Answer (score 1):

No need to create functions. `car` and `cdr` will do.

```
(define get-page-number car)
(define get-words cdr)

(get-page-number p3) ; ==> 32
(get-words p3)       ; ==> ("the" "rug" "rats" "slept" "on")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(define get-page-number car)
```